# Send Html images over http server?

Tags: java, image, networking, server

I have a java server socket (or http server, everyone calls it something different), and I am trying to display an image. Right now, I am just using an image hosting website, then linking it from there, but I would like to know, if I could send images through my connection? Here is my code, it is only one class,

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOEXception;
import java.new.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner
public class main {
public static void main(String argumentsCanBeNamedAnything[]) throws 
IOException {
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(80);
System.out.println("Listening");
while(true) {
try(Socket socket = server.accept()) {
String daCode = "";
File file = new File("index.html");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
String i = sc.nextLine();
daCode+=i;
}
String httpResponse = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n" + daCode;
socket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
}
}
}
```

I would like to be able to have an image in the same directory as index.html, and then be able to send that image so I don't have to use an image hosting website. Any idea is a good idea :)

Comment: You'd have to host the image on your server (the same one running the above code), and then send an HTML file with a correct image tag that will load the image.

Comment: You might want to check out O'Reily's *Learning Java* which has a small web server written entirely in Java, just like you have.  It's not much larger than your example either, the basics are not hard.

Comment: This is the server, if I would have the image on my machine, and then send it with <img src="path"> then it wouldn't show up

Comment: Yes it would.  I said "host the image on your server" so it would certainly show up.  You can start by testing on your own machine, that's what I do (and yes this works for servers, I've written a few).

Comment: How would I "host the image"?

Comment: @markspace I am reading the online pdf version of the book, and I see what you say, sorry to say your wrong, I was wrong. Thanks a lot for showing me about that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle all files with the same piece of code. Once you have an input stream that reads from the file, you should copy all bytes to the socket output stream. So first you 
should get an input stream like this:

```
String filename = ...
File file = new File(filename);
InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Then you should get an output stream connected to the socket:

```
OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
```

Now you can write the HTTP response like this:

```
write(output, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
write(output, "\n\n");
copyAllBytes(input, output);
```

The write method would look like this:

```
void write(OutputStream output, String s) throws IOException {
    output.write(s.getBytes());
}
```

And the copyAllBytes would look like this:

```
void copyAllBytes(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws IOException {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int n;
    while ((n = input.read(buf)) != -1) {
        output.write(buf, 0, n);
    }
}
```

Ideally you should also send a "Content-Type" header that indicates the nature and format of the document. Headers should also be written to the socket output, here is a simple example:

```
write(output, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
write(output, "\n");
write(output, "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
write(output, "\n\n");
copyAllBytes(input, output);
```